# Debugging after migration

Tags: 7, entities, media

I just migrate my website to a new hoster and I get many errors based on files/images problems. Can somebody help me with that ?

I have this error on every page :

> Notice: Undefined index: default_widget in
>   FieldInfo->prepareInstanceWidget() (line 580 of
>   .../www/modules/field/field.info.class.inc). Notice:
>   Undefined index: default_widget in FieldInfo->prepareInstanceWidget()
>   (line 588 of
>   .../www/modules/field/field.info.class.inc). Notice:
>   Undefined index: module in FieldInfo->prepareInstanceWidget() (line
>   591 of .../www/modules/field/field.info.class.inc).

And this one :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_field_load() in
>   .../www/modules/image/image.field.inc on line 195

So, after some investigations line 195 of image.field.inc :

```
function image_field_load($entity_type, $entities, $field, $instances, $langcode, &$items, $age) {
  file_field_load($entity_type, $entities, $field, $instances, $langcode, $items, $age);
}
```

But I didn't change anything in my files.

Comment: Have you tried flushing all caches in this new environment?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Can you reproduce this on your local? If it works fine on your local then probably some config is wrong on settings.php/.htaccess or the media directory for the new hoster.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. Actually I made another proper install and everything works just fine. I think it was kind of random bug which happened during restoration.

Comment: Cool, glad it worked out